# DB design for M:N table with time interval

Tags: mysql, sql

i would like to ask you a design question:

I am designing a table that makes me scratch my head, not sure what the best approach is, i feel like i am missing something:

There are two tables A and B and one M:N relationship table between them. The relationship table has right now these values:
A.ID, B.ID, From, To

Bussiness requirements:
At any time, A:B relation ship can be only 1:1 
A:B can repeat in time as defined by From and To datetime values, which specify an interval

example: Car/Driver.
Any car can have only 1 Driver at any time
Any Driver can drive only 1 car at any time (this is NOT topgear, ok? :) )
Driver can change the car after some time, and can return to the same car

Now, i am not sure:
- what PK should i go with? A,B is not enough, adding From and To doesnt feel right, maybe an autoincrement PK?
-any way to enforce the bussiness requirements by DB design?
-for business reason, i would prefer it not to be in a historical table. Why? Well, let's assume the car is rented and i want to know, given a date, who had what car rented at that date. Splitting it into historical table would require more joinst :(

I feel like i am missing something, some kind of general patter ... or i dont know....

Thankful for any help, so thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are actually missing anything. I think you've got a handle on what the problem is.

I've read a couple of articles about how to handle "temporal" data in a relational database.

Bottom line consensus is that the traditional relational model doesn't have any builtin mechanism for supporting temporal data.

There are several approaches, some better suited to particular requirements than others, but all of the approaches feel like they are "duct taped" on.

(I was going to say "bolted on", but I thought at tip of the hat to Red Green was in order: "... the handyman's secret weapon, duct tape", and "if the women don't find you handsome, they should at least find in you handy.")

---

As far as a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY for the table, you could use the combination of `(a_id, b_id, from)`. That would give the row a unique identifier.

But, that doesn't do anything to prevent overlapping "time" ranges.

There is no declarative constraint for a MySQL table that prevents "overlapping" datetime ranges that are stored as "start","end" or "start","duration", etc. (At least, in the general case. If you had very well defined ranges, and triggers that rounded the `from` to an even four hour boundary, and a duration to exactly four hours, you could use a UNIQUE constraint. In the more general case, for any ol' values of `from` and `to`, the UNIQUE constraint does not work for us.

A `CHECK` constraint is insufficient (since you would need to look at other rows), and even if it were possible, MySQL doesn't actually enforce check constraints.

The only way (I know of) to get the database to enforce such a constraint would be a `TRIGGER` that looks for the existence of another row for which the affected (inserted/updated) row would conflict.

You'd need both a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger and a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger. The trigger would need to query the table, to check for the existence of a row that "overlaps" the new/modified row

```
SELECT 1
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.a_id = NEW.a_id
   AND t.b_id = NEW.b_id
   AND t.from <> OLD.from
   AND < (t.from, t.to) overlaps (NEW.from,NEW.to) >
```

Obviously, that last line is pseudocode for the actual syntax that would be required.

The line before that would only be needed in the `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger, so we don't find (as a "match") the row being updated. The actual check there would really depend on the selection of the `PRIMARY KEY` (or `UNIQUE KEY`)(s).

With MySQL 5.5, we can use the `SIGNAL` statement to return an error, if we find the new/updated row would violate the constraint. With previous versions of MySQL, we can "throw" an error by doing something that causes an actual error to occur, such as running a query against a table name that we know does not exist.

And finally, this type of functionality doesn't necessarily have to be implemented in a database trigger; this could be handled on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

How about three tables:
TCar, TDriver, TLog

TCar
pkCarID
fkDriverID
name

A unique index on driver ensures a driver is only ever in one car. Turning the foreign key
fkDriverID into a 1:1 relation ship.

TDriver
pkDriverID
name

TLog
pkLogID (surrogate pk)
fkCarID
fkDriverID
from
to

With 2 joins you will get any information you describe. if you just need to find Car data by driverID or driver data by cardid you can do it with one join.

Answer (score 0):

thank you everyone for you input, so far i am thinking about this approach, would be thankful for any criticism/pointing out flaws:
Tables (pseudoSQLcode):

```
Car   (ID pk auto_increment, name)
Driver(ID pk auto_increment, name)
Assignment (CarID unique,DriverID unique,from Datetime), composite PK (CarID,DriverID)
AssignmentHistory (CarID unique,DriverID unique,from Datetime,to Datetime) no pk
```

of course, CarID is a FK to Car(ID) and DriverID is a FK to Driver(ID)

the next stage are two triggers (and boy oh boy, i hope this can be done in mysql (works on MSSSQL, but i dont have a mysql db handy right now to test):

!!! Warning, MSSQL for now

```
create trigger Assignment _Update on Assignment instead of update as
    delete Assignment 
      from Assignment 
           join inserted 
             on (    inserted.CarID= Assignment .CarID
                  or inserted.DriverID= Assignment .DriverID)
                and ( inserted.CarID<> omem.CarID or inserted.DriverID<> omem.DriverID)
    insert into Assignment 
    select * from inserted;



create trigger Assignment _Insert on Assignment  after delete as
    insert into Assignment_History
    select CarID,DriverID,from,NOW() from deleted;
```

i tested it a bit and it seems for each bussiness case it does what i need it to do